# Wordpress add_action undefined offset 0 in plugin.php line 925 and 943

Tags: wordpress, function, action, offset

I have a public function to attach taxonomies to custom post types.  I am getting this error code in Wordpress when debugging is set to true:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\yanjep-dev\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 925
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\yanjep-dev\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 943
```

This repeats 9 times each.

I have isolated the problem to an add_action function here:

```
add_action( 'init',
                call_user_func_array( 'register_taxonomy', array( $taxonomy_name, $post_type_name, $args ) )
            );
```

The entire function is here:

```
public function add_taxonomy( $name, $args = array(), $labels = array() )
{
    if( ! empty( $name ) )
    {           
        // We need to know the post type name, so the new taxonomy can be attached to it.
        $post_type_name = $this->post_type_name;

        // Taxonomy properties
        $taxonomy_name      = strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $name ) );
        $taxonomy_labels    = $labels;
        $taxonomy_args      = $args;

        if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy_name ) )
        {
            //Capitilize the words and make it plural
            $name       = ucwords( str_replace( '_', ' ', $name ) );
            $plural     = $name . 's';

            // Default labels, overwrite them with the given labels.
            $labels = array_merge(

                // Default
                array(
                    'name'                  => _x( $plural, 'taxonomy general name' ),
                    'singular_name'         => _x( $name, 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                    'search_items'          => __( 'Search ' . $plural ),
                    'all_items'             => __( 'All ' . $plural ),
                    'parent_item'           => __( 'Parent ' . $name ),
                    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent ' . $name . ':' ),
                    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit ' . $name ), 
                    'update_item'           => __( 'Update ' . $name ),
                    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New ' . $name ),
                    'new_item_name'         => __( 'New ' . $name . ' Name' ),
                    'menu_name'             => __( $name ),
                ),

                // Given labels
                $taxonomy_labels

            );

            // Default arguments, overwitten with the given arguments
            $args = array_merge(

                // Default
                array(
                    'label'                 => $plural,
                    'labels'                => $labels,
                    'public'                => true,
                    'show_ui'               => true,
                    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
                    '_builtin'              => false,
                ),

                // Given
                $taxonomy_args

            );

            // Add the taxonomy to the post type
            add_action( 'init',
                call_user_func_array( 'register_taxonomy', array( $taxonomy_name, $post_type_name, $args ) )
            );
        }
        else
        {               
            add_action( 'init', array($this, 'add_taxonomy_to_post_type'));
        }
    }
}
```

I am working locally using Xampp.  If I comment out the action, the notices disappear.  I know it has something to to with the number of arguments, but I can't solve it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, add_action requires two arguments: the filter (`register_taxonomy`, and the `function name` to call.

AFAIK, `add_action` needs to reference an actual function, and you cannot pass in a `call_user_func_array` call. If you trace the code in WP, you'll see that `add_action` in turn calls `add_filter`, which in turn calls `_wp_filter_build_unique_id`, which is where your error is being thrown.  If you investigate that code, you'll see it's expecting either a string - as in the function name to call (such as `register_my_taxonomy`), or else an array for class methods (following the PHP standard way).  Examples:

```
add_action('init', 'register_my_taxonomy'); // Call a standard function
add_action('init', array($this, 'register_my_taxonomy'); // call a public class method
add_action('init', array(__CLASS__, 'register_my_taxonomy'); // call a public static method
```

So, since it appears you are working in a class, in your `add_action('init'...)` call, I'd recommend changing it to reference a class function:

```
        add_action( 'init',
            array($this, 'register_my_taxonomy')
        );
```

And in your class, create the function `register_my_taxonomy` which **loops over your taxonomies** and calls `register_taxonomy` directly.